# NGINX - No input file specified

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

> Just want to let everyone know before I posted this question I checked
>   every single thread on stackoverflow about this issue.

**The aim:**

Run two apps under one domain, first app on the root (/) and second app under the URI (/learn).

```
http://example.com/ - first app
http://example.com/learn - second app
```

**The problem:**

The main app works perfectly, but the learn app is showing a white page with "No input file specified.".

**My file structure:**

```
/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/main/public/index.php
/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/learn/public/index.php
```

**My NGINX configuration:**

```
root "/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/main/public";

location ^~ /learn {
    root    "/srv/users/serverpilot/apps";
    try_files   $uri /learn/public/index.php?$query_string;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        add_header X-debug-message $document_root$fastcgi_script_name always;
        include       fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/srv/users/serverpilot/run/learn.php-fpm.sock;
    }
}

location / {
    try_files     $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include       fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/srv/users/serverpilot/run/main.php-fpm.sock;
        try_files     $uri =404;
    }
 }
```

> **In addition:**
>
> 1. I know the fastcgi_pass sockets are working because I've been
>      running these two apps under different domains but in the same
>      server in question.
> 2. I added the **add_header X-debug-message $document_root$fastcgi_script_name" always;** to see what the response header would show, and it shows that the
>      SCRIPT_FILENAME is 
>      /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/learn/public/index.php which exists and is the exact file I am trying to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh lordy! What a wild hunt!

Okay the reason this configuration wasn't working is because aside from **fastcgi_params** you can also set **php_value[doc_root]** which will overwrite your **$document_root** which is commonly used in the **SCRIPT_FILENAME** parameter. So check your **php.ini** files always to make sure **php_value[doc_root]** is not set when you have apps that are being served from different directories otherwise it just wont pick them up. In the case that you are just serving a single app from a single directory you need not worry.

Comment: where is that php_value? I don't see it inside php.ini

Comment: php.ini has `doc_root =` value